# Ant Design: Adding margin and padding provoke markup twitches

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, antd

[image]

[image]

If I add `margin` and `padding` for this class, it starts twitching like on first GIF.

If I remove `margin` and `padding` everything is good, but I need them for styling.

What causing this and how can I fix it?

1 GIF

```
.ant-layout.ant-layout-has-sider {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0 0 0;
}
```

2 GIF

```
.ant-layout.ant-layout-has-sider {
  max-width: 1440px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it will help someone: add `hasSider` prop for Antd Layout component